# how do you create a multi-threaded asp.net ajax update panel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, multithreading, updatepanel

how do you create a multi-threaded asp.net ajax update panel?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with an UpdatePanel, the last async postback wins.

Comment: ok, how do i fix timeouts on UpdatePanels? It seems that after constant use of it, it just stops async'ing. I've set the updatepanel to Conditional.

Comment: That is a loaded question, would have to see how you are using them?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The update panel isn't designed to be multi-threaded. You can have an Ajax request go to the server which calls a server side method that can spawn multiple threads, but the update panel itself cannot be made multi threaded.